Books to learn topology of projective space
I find the following question interesting.
How can I prove formally that the projective plane is a Hausdorff space?
I am interested to learn about the topology of projective spaces. Is there any specific subject where we study the topology of projective space? It will be helpful if anyone suggests some references.

The question you linked has a bunch of references. Most of them take the attitude that projective space is just an example of a quotient of a nice space by a finite-group action, and study that more general problem. You're unlikely to find a book specifically about projective spaces, although almost every topology book will use them as examples of various things. Learning the more general theorems is probably  a useful endeavor, BTW.

I would recommend  "Projective Geometry" by Fortuna, Friggerio, and Pardini. It is a very exercise focused book. The english version can be found here

The title is Projective geometry, so it would be nice to explain how much of this book is actually topology, and how much is geometry.

I guess any book of general topology should give you the basics to study the topology of Projective Space, as it stands the question is quite vague.
A standard reference is "Topology" by Munkres.

That won't give you knowledge about the topology of this space, only tools to learn it
